# XAML file format for Beyond Compare

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, file-format, beyondcompare

Has someone created a file format for XAML files, to use with [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/). Although xml format suits xaml files and using [XML Tidied and XML tidied with attributes sorted](http://weblogs.asp.net/lorenh/archive/2008/11/19/comparing-xml-files-with-beyond-compare-3-brilliant.aspx) formats can make it more powerful, I am planning to create a custom file format for XAML based on these two xml formats.

If anyone is using a file format for xaml then please share or let me know what other customizations I can do in xaml format I am creating.